# One-hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a csv file like this:

```
text short_text category
...  ...        ...
```

I have opened the file and stored it in a Pandas data frame like so:

```
filepath = 'path/data.csv'
train = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=0, delimiter=",")
```

The category fields for each record contains a list of categories, which is a string and each which category is in single quotes, like so:

```
['Adult'   'Aged'   'Aged   80 and over'   'Benzhydryl Compounds/*therapeutic use'   'Cresols/*therapeutic use'   'Double-Blind Method'   'Female'   'Humans'   'Male'   'Middle Aged'   'Muscarinic Antagonists/*therapeutic use'   '*Phenylpropanolamine'   'Tolterodine Tartrate'   'Urinary Incontinence/*drug therapy']
```

I wish to use this for machine learning by using one-hot encoding. I understand I can implement this using scikit-learn's sklearn.preprocessing package but am unsure how to do this.

Note: I don't have a list of all possible categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to [piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41151191/1391671), you can use [`sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
pd.concat([
    df.drop('category', 1),
    pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['category']), columns=mlb.classes_),
], 1)
```

In my tests, this was a few orders of magnitude faster, especially for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pd.value_counts` to help

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        text=list('ABC'),
        short_text=list('XYZ'),
        category=[list('abc'), list('def'), list('abefxy')]
    ))

df.category.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

[image]

or everything together

```
pd.concat(
    [df.drop('category', 1),
     df.category.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int)],
    axis=1
)
```

[image]